# JavaScript: Image doesn't scale in IE when dynamically added

Tags: javascript

when I dynamically add an image to a div the image doesn't scale when you resize the window in Internet Explorer.

I think it's more clear if I show two really simple examples:

The following example doesn't use JavaScript it's just plain html and it does what I want.
http://www.friendly-stranger.com/halp/ie-width/index.html

The next one uses JavaScript and if you resize the width of your browser window the image doesn't scale only the width gets smaller.
http://www.friendly-stranger.com/halp/ie-width/bad.html

This is a screenshot of both examples:
[image]
<sub>(source: [friendly-stranger.com](http://www.friendly-stranger.com/halp/ie-width/koala-squash.jpg))</sub>

The JavaScript code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'Koala.jpg';
        $('div').append(img);
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'Koala.jpg';
        img.style.height = 'auto';
        $('div').append(img);
    }); 
</script>
```

try this, i hope it'll work

Comment: Thanks that worked. Could you maybe explain why I have to add height auto?

Comment: IE doesn't automatically interpret that the height of the object should be changed after resizing. Therefore, we add height:auto in order to make IE understand what we want.